# Send Django Email User Register Confirmation with with custom header name

Tags: python, django, sendmail

I want to send Django email confirmation email, it shows the admin added email address (that we configure in settings.py) as the header of the newly arrived email, but I want to change it to something else my personal Header Title, like The Google Team, I want to replace my email as others showing in the picture.
https://prnt.sc/1mo2xeo
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"YOUR NAME <abc@domain.com>"` as the email address you send **from_email**.

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage 
email = EmailMessage()
email.subject = 'subject'
email.body = 'message'
email.from_email = 'YOUR NAME <abc@domain.com>'
email.to = ['to@domain.com']
email.send()
```